# sonata media - AWS CDN

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, sonata-admin, amazon-cloudfront, sonata-media-bundle

I have a functional symfony application with sonata media. Till now, I was using the filesystem. But the uploaded files are getting bigger and bigger and I'm willing to use a CDN to store these files (to avoid memory allocation issues).

I went [there](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) but this config fails. I have a working cloudfront distribution but the option "cloudfront" is not recognized under sonata_media in config.yml.

Then, I tried and used a S3 bucket. Configuration looks OK but after I submit my upload form in sonata_admin, I get an error message : "can't write the key"...

My IAM user has full s3 acccess and the bucket is public.

Here comes my config :

```
sonata_media:
db_driver: doctrine_orm
class:
    media:              Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    gallery:            Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    gallery_has_media:  Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia         Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
providers:

    #     allowed_mime_types: ['application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/rtf', 'text/html', 'text/rtf', 'text/plain', 'video/mp4']

    file:
        service:    sonata.media.provider.file
        resizer:    false
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
        cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.cloudront
        generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
        thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
        allowed_extensions: ['pdf', 'txt', 'rtf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pttx', 'odt', 'odg', 'odp', 'ods', 'odc', 'odf', 'odb', 'csv', 'xml', 'mp4']
        allowed_mime_types: ['application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/rtf', 'text/html', 'text/rtf', 'text/plain', 'video/mp4', 'video/webm']

    image:
        service:    sonata.media.provider.image
        resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple # sonata.media.resizer.square
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
        cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
        generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
        thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
        allowed_extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
        allowed_mime_types: ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']

    youtube:
        service:    sonata.media.provider.youtube
        resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
        cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
        generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
        thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
        html5: false

    dailymotion:
        service:    sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
        resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
        cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
        generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
        thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
contexts:
    default:  # the default context is mandatory
        download:
            strategy: sonata.media.security.forbidden_strategy
            mode: http
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file

        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

cdn:
    server:
        path: %s3_bucket_path%/uploads/media/

    #cloufront: ~
    #     path: http://%cloudfront_domain%.cloudfront.net/uploads/media
    #     distribution_id: %cloudfront_id%
    #     key: %cloudfront_key%
    #     secret: %cloudfront_secret%

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
        create:     false

    s3:
        bucket: %bucket_name"
        accessKey: %access_key%
        secretKey:%secret_key%
        region:
```

Answer (score 0):

It was correct to go "there" and the right config should look something like this:

```
cdn:
    server:
        path: http://%bucketname%.s3.amazonaws.com/blablafolder

filesystem:
    s3:
        bucket: %bucketname%
        accessKey: %aws_access%
        secretKey: %aws_secret%
        create: false
        region: us-east-1
        storage: standard
        acl: public
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

How come there's a "cloudfront" option under sonata_media.cdn in the "there" sample code ?

Comment: Another thing : my IAM user has full s3 access rights but I get a "can't write key" error when I try and submit my sonata admin form...

Comment: is the region key correct? it has to be the same as the one where the bucket is created.

Comment: Cloudfront is the AWS CDN while S3 is just a cloud filesystem. you can use both and have cloudfront cache files from s3 if you need to read from a bucket from around the world because CF is operating cross-region while S3 doesn't

Comment: My bucket is in Frankfurt, which eu-central-1 if I remember well.